# How to parse a TypeScript code base into ASTs

Tags: parsing, typescript, abstract-syntax-tree, decompiler

I want to parse TypeScript projects into ASTs.

I can parse single file by :

```
import ts = require("typescript");
var fs          = require('fs');
var util      = require('util');


const ast = ts.createSourceFile('sample.ts', fs.readFileSync('sample.ts').toString(), ts.ScriptTarget.ES6, true);

console.log("AST:"+util.inspect(ast));
```

I can even loop through the files and filter files by extension and run above code to generate ASt.

However I want to parse the whole project in such a way that the relationships (like imports) will be preserved in AST.

For example:

If, a.ts is referencing var x from b.ts as below:

a.ts:

```
var y = x;
```

b.ts:

```
var x = 5;
```

In this case signature of x in a .ts should be resolved as : b.ts.x or equivalent.

I just want all such relationships resolved in the ASts as I parse the .ts files one by one.

Answer (score 1):

You can load your project using

`ts.createProgram(rootNames: string[], options: CompilerOptions, host?: CompilerHost, oldProgram?: Program)`

rootNames is the list of all typescript files in your project. As far as I know, unless you declare type explicitly, AST will have no reference to it.

for eg. If you have

```
class MyClass { 
   // some code
}

let instance1 = new MyClass();
let instance2: MyClass = new MyClass();
```

In AST, node for `instance1` will have type property as undefined, for `instance2` type property will have proper `TypeReference`

For type checking you can use `Program.getTypeChecker()`. This returns a `TypeChecker` which can be used to analyse files in the program.